# AWT list selected item background color

Tags: java, awt

How can i change the background color of awt list selected item.

Swing component cannot be used to achieve this.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576853/how-to-change-background-color-of-the-selected-item-in-jlist-dynamically

Comment: Bodyloss: I cannot use swing components. That solution has swing component.

Comment: Oh dammit, my apologies. My morning coffee hadn't sunk in